# Visual studio remote system include statements

Tags: c++, g++, visual-studio-2017, ubuntu-16.04

I am creating a `C++` program to run on an Ubuntu `aarch64` (Nvidia TX1) device and am running into some errors with include statements.

I was using `cmake` as my compiler before and am trying to switch over to Visual Studio which I was more familiar with rather then working off a VM. The following include statements are what have errors, mainly to do with `Gstreamer`. All of the code in this program was successfully building and running before switching to Visual Studio.

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsink.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

I know VS is using `g++` to compile but I am not familiar with that.

Where and what statements do I need to include in my settings?

[Here are my Remote Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtL9w.png)

---

Update:

I got all the include statements working but I am running into an error. The following is the output from `Build`

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: RGB, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
1>Cleaning remote project directory
1>Validating architecture
1>Validating sources
1>Copying sources remotely to '192.168.1.14'
1>Starting remote build
1>Compiling sources:
1>main.cpp
1>Linking objects
1>g++: error : error : No such file or directory
1>Done building project "RGB.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: "I was using cmake as my compiler" - `cmake` is *not* a compiler.

Comment: @JesperJuhl you are correct about that. I guess it only manages the building process.

Answer (score 1):

**Is the build-essential OK on your Ubuntu device**? In my experience, Visual Studio would copy codes to the remote system and build them.

[image]

Comment: @LoganFawcett Did you try to include something name "error" ? Output in your update is a little strange.  Is "g++: error : error : No such file or directory" the original output?  You'd better check your includes.

Comment: I didn't try to include anything named "error". I agree that the output is strange. I may be including something incorrectly.
Project>Properties>VC++ Directories>Include Directories
`include;include/glib-2.0/glib$(IncludePath)`
Project>Properties>C/C++>Additional Include Directories
`/usr/include/glib-2.0;/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include;/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0;/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/include/;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)`
Project>Properties>Linker>Additional Dependencies
`include/glib-2.0/glib;/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst;%(AdditionalDependencies)`

Comment: It might be in your source code, not the Include Directories.